# Sort quote items in Magento2

Tags: magento2, sorting, quoteitem

In Magento2, how to sort Quote Items?

The code I have is her:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
class TestApp 
    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface, \Magento\Framework\AppInterface{
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
            SortOrder $sortOrder,
            SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteriaInterface
    ){
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend'); // or 'adminhtml', depending on your needs
        $this->_sortOrder = $sortOrder;
        $this->_searchCriteriaInterface = $searchCriteriaInterface;
    }
    public function getCurrentPage(){}
    public function setCurrentPage($currentPage){}
    public function getFilterGroups(){}
    public function setFilterGroups(array $filterGroups = NULL){}
    public function getSortOrders(){}
    public function setSortOrders(array $sortOrders = NULL){}
    public function getPageSize(){}
    public function setPageSize($currentPage){}
    protected function getSearchCriteria(){
        $searchcriteriaint = $this->_searchCriteriaInterface;
        $searchcriteriaint->setSortOrders(array($this->getSortOrder()));
        return $searchcriteriaint;
    }
    protected function getSortOrder(){
        $sortorder = $this->_sortOrder;
        $sortorder->setField('color')->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_ASC);
        return $sortorder;
    }
    public function launch(){
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        // // get quote items collection
        // $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        // // get array of all items what can be display directly
        $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems($this->getSearchCriteria());
        foreach($items as $key => $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $_product = $item->getProduct();
            $product = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
            echo 'Type: '.$item->getProductType().'<br/>';
            echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br/>';
            echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br/>';
            echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br/>';
            echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br/>';
            echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br/>';
            echo "<br />";
        }
        // return $this->_response;
    }
    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('TestApp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use getItems() plugin to Sort Quote Items:

Create After Plugin

**MODULE/etc/di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart">
        <plugin name="item_filter" type="[Your]\[Module]\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**[Your][Module]\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart:**

```
public function afterGetItems(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart $subject){
     $items = [];
     $totalItems = [];
     $itemAdded = [];

     foreach ($subject->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $totalItems[] = $item->getId();

        if(/*Your Condition*/){
           $itemAdded[] = $item;
           $items[] = $item;
        }

     }
     $result = array_diff($totalItems, $itemAdded);

     foreach ($result as $quoteid) {
        if($quoteid){
            $item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemById($quoteid);
            $items[] = $item;
        }
     }
    
    return $items;
}
```

**Edit by [Black](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/66769/black)**: The concept is simple. You have to intercept the quote, then get the items and save them in your wished order into an array. Then give that array back.

Comment: Where does Cart.php go? Model, Block, Controller? Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Create Cart.php in  YourModule/Plugin/Checkout/Block/here.

Comment: Can you put some  real code, like "echo ' Something'; " after " //Your Business Logic To Sort Items ", so that one can see that the change has taken place? Thanks

Comment: check updated answer @Supersonic. Accept it if works.

Comment: What could " /*Your Condition*/ " be, for example? Thanks!

Comment: This is very good, complete answer.

Comment: Dear sir, could you provide a complete Answer? I am willing to validate your answer. Have you tried this code yourself? Thanks! @Anime, are you also asking for a complete answer?

Comment: He's trying to sort the array of quotes along with their ids. At last he fetches the object of those quotes. I'm in bed now. Tomorrow I will post complete answer.

Comment: @Supersonic /*Your Condition*/  is upon your requirement...

Comment: @RizwanKhan this does not seem to work with pagination, atleast for me any ideas?

Comment: @harri you have pagination on cart page?

Comment: Well think its default, when you have over like 20 products

Comment: Had a bit of a nightmare with figuring it out in that case so stopped the pagination for now as not sure it is really gonna come to being a problem

Comment: oh ok, please add up the answer when you figure it out, it will be helpful for community.